# OSX : get size on disk for a file/directory

Tags: macos, cocoa, file, filesystems, macos-carbon

I am looking for a way (the fastest, working for both files and directory and accurate) to get the size of disk (not the file size) of a file or directory, using either:
- BSD functions
- Carbon functions
- Cocoa functions

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a file URL, you can use -[NSURL resourceValuesForKeys:error:] to get these values:

- NSURLFileSizeKey; <-- file size in bytes
- NSURLFileAllocatedSizeKey; <-- file size on disk